# Having problems with the flow of my c# program

Tags: c#, debugging, timer, event-handling

I'm writing a program that has multiple event handlers in it, new territory for me. One event handler watches a folder and when a file is moved into it it opens the file, gets one piece of information out of the file, stores that data in a list of objects and then moves the file to another folder. The second event handler is based off of a timer where it's interval is set for 10 seconds. When the timer elapses it loops through the list I've loaded up and checks to see if the timestamp of when the item was loaded to the list is more than 1 minute old and if it is then it just displays a message to the console. I have two main problems: first) the message that should be displayed to the console once a minute is displaying more often than it should (about once every 15 seconds as opposed to once a minute) and 2) when I try to debug the program and it gets to the timer event handler it jumps all over the place that doesn't follow any logical path to me (I'm probably wrong). Please, can someone help me out? Any help would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
public class fileObject
    {
        public string strPONumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime dtArrival { get; set; }
    }
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    public static void Main()
    {
        Run();
    }

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public static void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("redefined");
        List<fileObject> lstPONums = new List<fileObject>();

        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\Users\z088476\Desktop\FolderA\";



        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*";

        // Add event handlers.

        Console.WriteLine("before event");

        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler((sender, e) => OnChanged(sender, e, lstPONums));


        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e, lstPONums));
        aTimer.Interval=10000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;


        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e, List<fileObject> lstPONumbers)
    {
        fileObject fObj = new fileObject();
        string strLine = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            strLine = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        string strDelim = strLine.Substring(3,1);
        List<string> lstSplit = new List<string>();
        lstSplit = strLine.Split(Convert.ToChar(strDelim)).ToList();
        fObj.strPONumber = lstSplit[30];
        fObj.dtArrival = DateTime.Now;
        lstPONumbers.Add(fObj);
        File.Move(e.FullPath, @"C:\Users\z088476\Desktop\FolderC\" + e.Name);
    }


    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e, List<fileObject> lstPONumbers)
    {

        if (lstPONumbers.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (fileObject fo in lstPONumbers)
            {
                DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - fo.dtArrival;
                if (duration.TotalMinutes > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("IT IS MORE THAN 1 MIN!!!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `aTimer.Interval=10000;` is 10 seconds, not 1 minute. 1000ms per second * 60 seconds, the value should be 60000 if you want the timer to fire every minute. The issue with debugging and "jumping" is probably that you are taking more than 10 seconds to debug and another breakpoint gets hit in a different timer elapsed tick. Try turning the timer off at the beginning of the `OnTimedEvent` and turn it back on at the end.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick response Ron. That takes care of one of my problems. Does anyone know why when I debug and step into the timer's event handler it just jumps all over the code instead of following a linear path?

Comment: I edited my comment to address your other issue...

Comment: I think the elapsed event is called on a different thread, hence the jumping in code while debugging.

Comment: One tip, you can pause other threads in the "Threads" window in visual studio.

Comment: It "jumps all over the code" because you have multiple threads and the breakpoint displayed will depend upon which thread hit a breakpoint first

Comment: Thanks for everything guys, one last thing though. Can anyone tell me how to reset the timer to start counting as if it was starting to count from the first iteration? This program will run for hours and I don't like the idea of the timer starting and stopping every minute and keeping track of the whole amount of time over those hours when all I care about is just each segment of a minute.

Comment: The timer does not accumulate time, it resets itself.